# syntax error while getting jobId in a SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using the following code in a SSIS package to get the jobid. It was working fine in DEV server but failed in text as syntax error. Now is failing in dev server as well as a SYNTAX error.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX) =
'SELECT jobId = CAST(CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, '+ ? + ') as varchar(50));'
EXEC(@sql);
```

Yes, this is the first step to execute SQL TASK in ssis which takes a jobId and pass the job ID to another step. The error I am getting is

> Set @jobI: Error: Executing the query " Declare @sql varchar(max) = "select jobId = cast(C..." failed with the following error: "incorrect syntax near '('.

Any suggestion on how to make this running .

Thanks

Comment: *"as syntax error"*? What was said error? Why is your SQL dynamic too, isn't this just a parametrised statement?

Comment: What value is the variable/parameter set to when the error occurs?  And does this value differ from the successful executions?